# Use a different DataTemplate with the same key if called from different exe

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate, resourcedictionary

In a `wpf.dll`, I define a DataTemplate with a key `MorphControl` in ResourceDictionary XAML:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
       <DataTemplate x:Key="MorphControl">
        <n1:m1 />
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

If this `wpf.dll` is called by an exe ( say, `A.exe`), then I would like the above `FindResource("MorphControl")` to return `m1` related resrouce.

But, there is a possibility that `wpf.dll` is being called by another exe ( say, `B.exe`), in `B.exe`, the same key is being redefined to use another value, ie, inside `B.exe`, this definition exists:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
       <DataTemplate x:Key="MorphControl">
        <n2:m2 />
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

So when `B.exe` is calling, I want  `FindResource["MorphControl"]` to return `m2` related resource.

I want to use the same `wpf.dll`  for both `A.exe` and `B.exe`. And I don't want to move the `MorphControl` definition from `wpf.dll` to `A.exe`-- it has to remain at `wpf.dll`.

Also, this particular Resource key must remain the same throughout because  inside `wpf.dll`, I have a `DataTemplateSelector` logic that I don't want to touch

How to do this, or is this possible?

Comment: This sounds almost like a `TemplateSelector` that could call your `WPF.dll`. But How have you got your `WPF.dll` structured? You would have to have some sort of mechanism inside your `WPF.dll` that would expect some parameters and then try to match them with available resources.

Comment: @XAMlMAX, `TemplateSelector` works on a unique key-pair. In this case here, the key has to be the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer ( same one as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8098794/3834)): just define the `ResourceDictionary.MergeDictionaries` with `wpf.dll` `DataTemplate` first,  follow by `B.exe` `DataTemplate`. In other words:

```
<Application.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                  <ResourceDictionary Source="wpf.dll.xaml"/>
                  <ResourceDictionary Source="B.exe.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
   </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one unorthodox way that should work (I didn't try it, but based on some other things I did, it should work):

Create two ResourceDictionaries, one for each exe in two separate files.
Create class that will inherit `ResourceDictionary`, lets call it `ExeAwareDictionary`. It should have to private fields/properties of type `ResourceDictionary` and you should override `item[object]` property.
When getter for `item` property is called, you can check which exe it is (by checking current process) and return resource with given key from appropriate "inner" dictionary.

You might want to also override some other properties like `Keys` and `Values`, etc.

Comment: OP clearly stated "_I have a DataTemplateSelector logic that I don't want to touch_".

Comment: And he doesn't have to. 
DataTemplateSelector will do its job and request DataTemplate from wpf.dll by key but it will receive different result depending on .exe file it is executing in.